# PHP Amazon SDK, S3 Bucket Access Denied

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I try for the first time to use the PHP AWS SDK ("aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.19") to use S3.

I created a bucket : 'myfirstbucket-jeremyc'

I created a policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myfirstbucket-jeremyc/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I applied the policy to a group and then created a user 's3-myfirstbucket-jeremyc' in this group.

My PHP code is :

```
<?php
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

error_reporting(E_ALL);

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$s3Client = S3Client::factory([
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $_SERVER['AWS_S3_CLIENT_KEY'],
        'secret' => $_SERVER['AWS_S3_CLIENT_SECRET']
    ],
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'scheme' => 'http'
]);

$result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
    'Bucket' => 'myfirstbucket-jeremyc',
    'Key' => 'text.txt',
    'Body' => 'Hello, world!',
    'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ));
```

But i get this **error :**

> Error executing "PutObject" on
>   "http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myfirstbucket-jeremyc/text.txt";
>   AWS HTTP error: Client error: PUT
>   http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myfirstbucket-jeremyc/text.txt
>   resulted in a 403 Forbidden response

Do you know where i'm wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're setting the ACL for the new object but you haven't allowed `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

Comment: Thanks ! It's works by commenting the line for the ACL or adding "s3:PutObjectAcl" in policy.